# Getting Tkinter text widget to show the latest addition

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

My application uses a Tkinter text widget to display something to the user every time it calls an API. As the API is called numerous times, the text that is displayed goes beyond the scope of the text area. So, the user has to go on to the text area and scroll to know the present status. Is there some way I can get the text widget to scroll a little down every time something new comes up?

The program does the following every time it has something to say:

```
text.insert(index,'Fetching names, authentication tokens and designations...\n')
index+=1
root.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after [see](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method) method:

```
text.see(END) % for example
```

Comment: thanks! nice blog you got there